# modelform id field being passed as REQUIRED field

Tags: django, forms, field, required, formset

The site I am building uses modelforms several times. Until now validation of the forms using is_valid has gone smoothly. Now, a new model I've created has decided that the id field (which is generated automatically for model forms) is a required field. I am rendering the fields manually in the template and am not rendering the id field. This has not been a problem with any of my modelforms until now, since it has never been registered as a required field. With this problematic model however, since I am not rendering the field, it gets returned empty and so doesn't pass validation.

I realize that I could solve the problem by rendering the field, but I'd like to understand whats going on here. Why has it decided, seemingly randomly, that the id is required?

Here is the problematic model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    budgetcatagory=models.ForeignKey(BudgetCatagory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    enName=models.CharField(max_length=30, default ="")
    detail=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    layout=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="normal")
    unit=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit_description=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    unit_price=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    QTY=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    param1=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    param2=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    param3=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    param4=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent=models.CharField(max_length=30, default = "0")
    cost_ave=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    cost_min=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    cost_max=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    total_cost=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    choiceList=(
            ('choice1',param1),
            ('choice2',param2),
    )
    ItemChoice=models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=choiceList,
        default='',
    )
    objects=ItemManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is how I am populating the form before sending to template:

```
else:
    #populate
    I=Item.objects.filter(budgetcatagory__user_id=U.id)
    C=BudgetCatagory.objects.filter(user_id=U.id)

    #initiate initial catagories and items for new user
    if (not I.exists()) or (not C.exists()):
        Item.objects.filter(budgetcatagory__user_id=U.id).delete()
        BudgetCatagory.objects.filter(user_id=U.id).delete()
        InitiateNewUser(U)
        I=Item.objects.filter(budgetcatagory__user_id=U.id)
        C=BudgetCatagory.objects.filter(user_id=U.id)
    FormsetItem=ItemFormSet(queryset=I)
    FormsetCat=CatFormset(queryset=C)

return render(request,'getdata/budgetmachine.html', {'FormsetItem':FormsetItem, 'FormsetCat':FormsetCat })
```

And here is how I am populating the form from the POST:

```
if request.method=='POST':
            #Save
            FormsetItem=ItemFormSet(request.POST,queryset=Item.objects.filter(budgetcatagory__user_id=U.id))
            FormsetCat=CatFormset(request.POST)
            if FormsetItem.is_valid():
```

I've been breaking my head against this for days. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:

Alasdair, following your answer I renderered the entire formset automatically {{ formset }} to ensure that all necessary fields would be rendered. It is now failing validation for an even weirder reason:

```
 {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

Obviously I haven't set up my id as a choice field as I haven't set it up at all. it gets generated automatically. I am slowly going insane! Any help would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The `id` field is required for model formsets, you have to include it in the template. Perhaps you were using individual model forms before, where it isn't required.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I've been trying to find info on that in the documentation with no luck. Can you point me to a place to read up on this?

Comment: In the docs for [using a model formset in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template), it says: *if you [render the fields manually] and you don’t iterate over the fields with a `{% for %}` loop, you’ll need to render the primary key field*.

Comment: Also, it is worth to be mentioned that adding`{{ id }}` somewhere to the form you actually add a hidden input `<input name="smth-0-id" value="123" id="id_smth-0-id" type="hidden">`

Comment: This was driving me crazy for 2 days, a small but critical point